# Redirect a specific subdomain to a different URL in apache2 linux server

Tags: linux, apache

Can someone help me Redirecting a specific subdomain to a different URL in the apache2 Linux server

Comment: Please read [ask]. This question contains no information about your situation, observations etc.

Answer (score 1):

make a file named `.htaccess`, and give it the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/page [L]
```

replace domain and address as needed

docs: [httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)